# Status of feet while making a bracha or davening

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, blessing, parts-of-the-body

In todays day and age where we no longer have homes with dirt floors:

- do you still need to cover your feet when making a bracha or davening?
- If so are socks enough?
- does it depend on the custom of the place you live?
- If not would that only apply to carpeted areas?
- is there a difference between being in a private home versus a public
  area?

Comment: perhaps document as part of the question a source that feet must be covered?

Answer (score 6):

I only know of covering ones feet being important while praying during the amidah (whether in private in public),

**"One should not pray wearing [only] his undershirt, bareheaded, or barefoot - if it is the custom of the people of that place to stand before their most respected people with shoes."** *[M"T Hilkhoth Tephilah 5:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2205n.htm#5)*

But this is in the context that if one does pray with out shoes while in a place in which it is customary to not be barefooted when in the presence of esteemed people it does not invalidate their amidah ([ibn 5:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2205n.htm)). I haven't heard of it being needed for a brakha.

Comment: +1 It would seem that both the US and Israel nowadays would be classified as requiring some sort of foot covering (sandal/shoe).

Comment: Yes most places in the world today i would imagine. I wonder how it would apply with socks, maybe if you are indoors in a place where one wouldn't wear shoes even if such a person was coming over (ie one own house) it would be ok to pray in socks since thats the normal foot wear in that situation? im not to sure about that.

Comment: @DoubleAA, many homes have a remove-your-shoes-at-the-door policy. I'm not sure what they'd do if their "most respected people" paid a visit, however.

Comment: @msh210 Plus "of that place" might have a slightly broader definition than each person's private home.

Comment: @DoubleAA, indeed; I was thinking, though, of a (geographical) place where such a policy is common.

Comment: Does this apply to socks?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Chayei Adam says in places where women go barefoot that's fine, in places where they're usually covered they should be covered.

Comment: Isn't that related to general tzniut not making a bracha or davening?

Comment: @Moshe, correct, I think I was confusing two questions here. A, I should be properly dressed (out of respect) when I daven, so what footwear is required. B, I shouldn't daven if there's an "exposed" woman nearby, what's "exposed" with regards to feet?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that a lot of this depends on the culture around a person.

My Zeidi for example, would not allow people to go around with only socks on under any circumstances. And a Bracha could never be said in slippers.  I imagine this has a lot to do with his 'proper' upbringing.

R. Aviner today, will never allow a person to go barefoot, but slippers and socks are ok.

Having your feet covered is about more than just "dirt floors". It is also a sense of dirtiness of the floor (you wouldn't eat off of it), as well as issues of respect and dignity.

Comment: My father z"l did not like us to go around without shoes. I felt that his dsailike was because mourners do not wear leather shoes.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok this was the same reason I learned - if somebody had a source, it would make a great answer.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That falls under ideas of human dignity and respect.  I was told because of mourners, because "people" don't walk without shoes, only animals do, because they are smelly, and a myriad of other reasons.

Comment: My Zeida as well did not like us to walk in socks.  It was a superstitious concern that, just like a mourner walks without shoes, so to if you walk with out shoes you may come to be a mourner.  It was not a Halacha or Torah concept as I understood it.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Angels don't either.

Comment: Angels don't what, wear leather shoes, or like people going around without them? Many angels tell people to take off their shoes

Comment: @bluejayke According to Rambam angels do not exist (or at least not as spiritual entities) they are merely the natural forces.

Comment: @bluejayke Angels are G-d’s natural laws. There are no powers besides G-d, and Rambam prohibited the prayer and worship of angels or any other force besides G-d.

Comment: @TurkHill so when the rambam wrote extensibly about the intelligence of angels, he  was only kidding?

Comment: @bluejayke The Rambam did not think angels existed as spiritual entities. They are merely the natural forces.

Comment: @TurkHill where does he that?

Comment: @bluejayke See Guide, 2:6 where he says that they are natural forces when he quotes the book of Psalms 104:4 which says the “elements are called angels, ‘who makes winds, His angels.’”