# Walking around indoors without shoes

Tags: halacha, minhag, children-parenting, shoes

Does anyone know of a source for the practice of not walking around indoors without shoes? (I am seeking an actual source, not speculation)

Comment: Never heard of this before. I know you're not looking for speculation, but there's some speculation [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1246628/jewish/Jews-Without-Shoes.htm).

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%95

Comment: @DoubleAA That's what I thought OP might be referring to, but that seems to be referring to walking barefoot outside the home, not inside, especially based on the source from the gemara ([*Shabbos* 129a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=129&format=text) and Rashi s.v. "מנעלים"; [*Shabbos* 152a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=152&format=text)). Alternatively, I also originally suspected that he might be referring to praying barefoot (related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14525) or studying Torah barefoot.

Comment: @Fred, he doesn't say barefoot at all; cf. your first comment.

Comment: @msh210 Fair enough. I was actually being imprecise in my previous comment; I should've written "without shoes" in the first sentence, rather than "barefoot." Anyway, those were just my initial thoughts, but I'm guessing OP is probably just referring to the (seemingly) unrelated practice linked in my first comment.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Jay.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking about differences in shoes rules following the place you are. If it is the case, where can I learn Hilchot shoes. I know that in hilchot Chalitsa thee are discussion about shoes.

Comment: This sounds to me as possibly a custom that probably developed locally, possibly after an event. Being without shoes is a sign of mourning - and could be regarded as liable to bring ayin hara on the place. It could be that once someone did this and soon afterwards a parent died, so forcing the person to be barefoot. People may have said that there was a causal effect, and so the custom arose.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Everyone I've spoken to who is aware of this practice explains it with some vague explanation involving aveilus/mourning.  One person said he thinks it's a kibbud av issue based on the aforementioned aveilus factor.  I am curious regarding the source, both for the sake of clarity, and also to ascertain it's relevance and applicability: does it only apply to a parent's house, and is it still applicable today when it is normal behavior to walk in one's house sans shoes and doesn't indicate aveilus any more than wearing non-leather footwear (ie sandals) does.

Comment: Again without a source (sorry) my family has a custom not to walk around in socks as it is a sign of mourning.

Comment: http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/15583

Comment: Probably not relevant. In a shiur on tumah, it was taught that one should have a special pair of shoes dedicated for their home or beis knesset that can be touched without requiring netilyat yadayim; tumah comes from outside the home. I wanna say Rabbi Moshe Feinstein has comment on wearing/not wearing shoes inside the home. Again, I'll try and source later B'N.

Comment: I've definitely seen this. I heard the reason was that we should walk above the ground, unlike animals. The tumah connection is not surprising to me. Finally, there is an inyan in tznius--at least for women--that toes be covered

Answer (score 3):

As recorded in [this Chabad article](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1246628/jewish/Jews-Without-Shoes.htm), walking barefoot is a sign of mourning, and we try to avoid signs of death as much as humanly possible.

In [this article](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/15583), quoted by [Gershon Gold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74034/walking-around-indoors-without-shoes#comment217274_74034), there's a practical reason: it's easier to walk with shoes on.

Comment: Is wearing crocs also a sign or mourning?

Comment: That could possibly be a nafka minah between the two answers. Considering that they're mutar for Tishah B'Av and Aveilim, perhaps yes, they would be, but I agree that's a huge chiddush.

Answer (score 2):

I lived for a while in a very strict Chassidic community. Walking around indoors without shoes was seen as an extremely serious offence, even when done with socks and stockings, and on a thick carpet.

The reason was that without shoes, one could be negatively affected by the ground's [*klipos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qliphoth).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also got the sense that it's more of a Chassidic thing, but I never heard this interesting explanation before. Did they ever happen to mention a source to you - I guess it would be a kabbalistic work - that gives this reason for the minhag? An authoritative  source would  be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mesechta Shabbos 129a, Pesachim 112a. One should sell their property for shoes so not to walk barefoot.

Rashi in Shabbos states, there is nothing more disgraceful than walking barefoot.

RAMA 2:6 states this is the halacha, forbidden to walk barefoot.

100% forbidden to dress inappropriately in a shul which includes not wearing socks (even if you have shoes on), and other things like shorts, etc.

Mishna Berurah 2:14 says that if you are in an Arab country where it is normal not to wear shoes than it is permitted. Stressing here ARAB countries.

Maaseh Avrohom (circa 1860 or so) quotes the Chesed L'Avrohom (master of Kabalah in both ARIZAL and Cordovo, circa 1600 or so), states that shouldn't walk barefoot because there is a ruach raah (evil spirit) on the ground connected to the snake from the Gan Eden times. However this doesn't apply to Eretz Yisroel when it is ruled by Jews (I am not getting into if this is those times now....too controversial for me).

I hope I gave enough sources with my explanations to satisfy the needs. Have a great Shabbos

Comment: Rama 2:6 is referring to barefoot with no shoes OR socks. I do not believe the Rama would have an issue with wearing only shoes or wearing only socks.